# Swift - Firebase - Friend list - Possibility to create groups of friends

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, friend

I would like to manage the friends I added in my app (with swift and Firebase)

*For example , I would like for a user (who have 15 friends)* :

- To create a group with 5 friends for example (the user could add a name for this group)
- To delete if necessary the group
- To send a message(textfield) to a group
- To send a message (textfield) to a user

I don't know how to do it. Could someone give me a clue ?

Thanks for helping me !

Have a nice day!

Comment: If this a good way to follow ? :https://github.com/1amageek/Salada ?

Comment: We are not a code writing service and you should try to write the code yourself. What you are asking for goes beyond the scope of this forum as well. Try to write some code and when you get stuck with a specific issue, post your code and your Firebase structure (as text!) and we'll take a look. In the meantime, please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)